# how to set local variable value, when use WSResponse

Tags: java, playframework

I am trying to set the value of a local variable, but this shows an error

> Local variable user_id defined in an enclosing scope must be final or
> effectively final
>
> Local variable username defined in an enclosing scope must be final or
> effectively final

how do I fix it?

it's my code:

```
int user_id;
String username;

WSRequest req1 = ws.url("https://www.example.com");
CompletionStage<WSResponse> rsp1 = req1.get();

rsp1.thenAccept((rs) -> {
        JsonNode result = rs.asJson();
        Boolean status = result.findPath("status").asBoolean();
        if (status == true) {
            user_id = result.findPath("user").findPath("id").asInt(); //error here
            username = result.findPath("user").findPath("uname").textValue(); //error here
        }
    }).toCompletableFuture().get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP request is handled asynchronously and you cannot set the values of the variables of the outer scope from the within the lambda function (from another thread) and use it in a synchronous fashion.

If you want to process the result synchronously, just wait for the request to complete and use it:

```
JsonNode result = rsp1.thenAccept(rs -> return rs.asJson()).toCompletableFuture().get();

Boolean status = result.findPath("status").asBoolean();
if (status) {
   ...
}
```